# Problems with SDK level checking

Tags: android, sdk, logcat

I am running tests on a 4.4.2 device and strange logs are coming up and the verification should prevent this:

Logcat:

```
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.AlarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle, referenced from method initTimer

I/dalvikvm: Could not find method requestPermissions, referenced from method MyActivity.requestPermissions
```

Methods class:

```
void requestPermissions() {

        List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

        final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            //verify permission

            return;
        }
        //normal flow

}



void initTimerGetRegions(Context context) { 

    AlarmManager processTimer = Memory.getInstance().getTimer(context);
    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(context, TimerReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntentAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1,
            intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        processTimer.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, pendingIntentAlarm);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        processTimer.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, pendingIntentAlarm);
    } else {
        processTimer.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, pendingIntentAlarm);
    }


}
```

Apparently the code is working on higher versions but the lower ones are crawling these logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> strange logs are coming up

They are perfectly normal.

> the verification should prevent this

No.

These are messages from the Dalvik VM, indicating that as it is loading in your class, it is having difficulty finding certain methods. That is because those methods are only available on newer versions of Android.

The key, though, is the first letter of your log lines: `I`. This is an informational message. It is not an error. So long as you do not attempt to *execute* any of this missing methods, everything is fine.

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks for the answer!